# wooden floor chipped from PC Case

Tags: wood, flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, damage

[image]

Do I just leave it? PC case had rubber legs but it was stuck to the floor and when I tried to flip it, part of the wooden floor came off with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What came off is the finish (urethane, polyurethane, or varnish), not the wood.

If left alone, it will absorb dirt, moisture and darken.

I would try a wipe on polyurethane and apply it with a q-tip. Your finish looks like gloss, so I would try that level of sheen. You can always dull it a bit with fine steel wool.

You should try to remove the rubber stain first. That can be done with a cleaner, such as Simple Green or Fantastik type cleaners.

Comment: Would this just be for aesthetics? I don't care for the looks but fear damage might expand after time, especially the glossy bits. How does fine steel wool darken it, won't that damage it further?

Comment: This is just aesthetics. That amount of raw wood will never lead to any real damage, although the wound may widen a bit over time. The steel wool would only be used to dull the finish if a gloss repair were too shiny.

Comment: It's not a high traffic area but would like to fix it, I'm only reluctant because I fear the PC case might get stuck again over it and by coating it might have uneven edges. How many coats with the q-tip?Do I also sand it first?

Comment: Also when you say it will absorb moisture, does that mean it poses a danger to the whole floor?

Comment: Do the repair as stated with a q-tip, and when you are ready to put the PC back, put felt pads over the rubber ones. This won't let the PC sit secure, but the chances of a computer sliding are pretty slim unless made to slide.

Comment: Will doing the q-tip and sanding create mess?

Comment: It shouldn't. Sand lightly just in the immediate area of the chip, maybe 1/4 inch on either side. Wipe with just a bit of mineral spirits or alcohol. Swab the new finish just past the immediate chip area. Let dry thoroughly (several days). If too shiny, buff gently with 0000 steel wool.

Comment: Okay, Do I just go over it with the qtip once, would that be sufficient? Is there a visible way of knowing how much is enough?

Comment: I would probably give it at least two coats, letting them dry in between according to package directions.

Comment: Package directions for minwax says wait 2 hours then recoat, if it's not dry however then wait 72 hrs, sand and recoat. I didn't pay attention to it that much so I applied first coat then left it for 10 hours and did a second without sanding. Would that hold or should I redo it properly ?

Comment: I would redo (after 3 days, sand lightly, recoat). After a few hours the finish is too hard to fully meld with the next coat, but is still off-gassing and that may interfere with the bond in a next coat. After 72 hours the off-gassing has pretty much ended.

Comment: Okay will wait till then. Just to make sure is it okay to use a 120 grit sandpaper lightly? And when I use qtip do I go over it in one sweep?

Comment: I would use a much finer sandpaper - 180 or 220, or a fine steel wool 000. If you are using the wipe-on poly, I would rub it in a bit in the middle and feather the edge with a light stroke.

Comment: thanks will try to do that. Is it alright to use 120 grit though since I can't find another easily available right now and steel wool is more messy I think.

Comment: It will work, but it might be just a bit less smooth than the rest of the floor.